# How to correctly set a JWT secret in Laravel with jwt-auth?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'd like to test the authentication of JWTs in my project as the JWTs will be sent from outside the app, and so they must be signed using the key from my application. Is this possible? Does anyone know of a site that allows you to sign a token using a secret?

I tried http://jwtbuilder.jamiekurtz.com/ but JWT-auth keeps returning `{"error":"token_invalid"}` if I enter the key which was returned by `jwt:generate`. This leads me to believe the key returned by this command is not actually the key used to sign JWTs in my application.

I'm using `php artisan jwt:generate` to generate a key, which returns the following:

```
jwt-auth secret [...] set successfully.
```

But where is it set? The `JWT_SECRET` variable in my .ENV file doesn't change, and if I perform a project wide search for the key it's not found.

Does this command work?

Laravel 5.3, jwt-auth 0.5.9.

Comment: Try running `php artisan jwt:secret`

Comment: this is returning an error There are no commands defined in the "jwt" namespace.' after installing jwt and running php artisan jwt:secret command in command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent testing in both 0.5.9 and 0.5.12 indicates that the `jwt:generate` command ONLY changes the value in `config/jwt.php` IFF it is the key in use. To see this for yourself, set the value in `.env` to be the same as in `config/jwt.php` and it WILL change the one in config the first time you run it but then it will break.

A bit of searching indicates that the dev has no plans to fix this for 0.5.*

I wrote a (admittedly rather ungainly single line) bash script that will create this JWT_SECRET in .env if it does not exist or update all occurrences of 'JWT_SECRET=':

```
env=".env"; secret="$(php artisan jwt:generate --show)"; oldsecrets="$(grep '^JWT_SECRET=' $env)"; if [ -z "$oldsecrets" ]; then sed -i "$ a JWT_SECRET=$secret" "$env"; else echo "$oldsecrets" | while IFS= read -r line ; do echo "$line"; sed -i -e "s/$line/JWT_SECRET=$secret/g" "$env"; done; fi
```

Answer (score 19):

Just run this command:

`php artisan jwt:secret`

[Reference](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/laravel-installation/)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Don't forget to set a secret key in the config file!

Since you can't find the key in a search, I think you haven't actually published the config:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"
```

The docs seem pretty clear and the issues on GitHub don't mention the problems you're having, so take a peek into them and see if you maybe skipped step. Happens to the best of us! https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation

Comment: I had already published the config, and I have a `jwt.php` file under `/config`. In this file there is the following line: `'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET', 'EAfZasuhuuhdgBLNtf07ZRXyQPcuKPEC'),`, however this key never changes when I run the `jwt:generate` command. It makes me think it's using a different key to generate the token.

Comment: Hmm, looking at the source code, it should set a key in your `.env` file. Are you getting the "Are you sure you want to override the secret key?" message? https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/develop/src/Console/JWTGenerateSecretCommand.php Else I would remove the package and its references and try with a new install.

Comment: No I'm not getting that message. Each time it just repeats the same `jwt-auth secret [...] set successfully.` with a different key.  I'll re-install.