# JWT Token Signature could not be verified error with external API login

Tags: laravel-5, jwt

In Laravel 5.8 / vuejs / vuex / mysql app I use jwt-auth and when I login into 
the system (standard auth with mysql users table) I use method :

```
export function setAuthorizationToken(token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`
}
```

and it worked ok.

Next I  remade SignUp/SignIn to use external API for SignUp/SignIn operations.
So my app needs to make SignUp/SignIn  with external API , but also I have requests for controls of my app to read/write data from/to mysql.

I remade SignIn request to external API with php curl in control action when user clicks SignIn button, like :

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

   // I run login method
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->admindashApi . '/api/login');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"));

            $userLoginData = [
                'email'    => $credentials['email'],
                'password' => $credentials['password'],
            ];
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userLoginData));

            $resp = curl_exec($ch);

            $respArray = json_decode($resp);
            if ( isset($respArray->success) and empty($respArray->success)) { // login fails - return error in responce
                $err = curl_error($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                $errorsArray     = [$respArray->data];
                $errors_message  = $respArray->data;

                return response()->json([
                    'error_code' => 1,
                    'message'    => $errors_message,
                    'errors'     => $errorsArray,
                    'rows_total' => 0,
                ], HTTP_RESPONSE_BAD_REQUEST /*HTTP_RESPONSE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR*/);

            } //if ( isset($respArray->success) and empty($respArray->success)) { // login fail

            $logged_user_token = $respArray->data->token;
            // if login was successful, I keep token

             // I need to get details of the logged user
            $loggedUser= null;

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->admindashApi . '/api/user');

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "Authorization: Bearer ".$logged_user_token
            ]);

            $resp = curl_exec($ch);

            $respArray = json_decode($resp);

            if ( isset($respArray->success) and empty($respArray->success)) { // details read fails - return error in responce
                $err = curl_error($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                $errorsArray     = [$respArray->data];
                $errors_message  = $respArray->data;

                return response()->json([
                    'error_code' => 1,
                    'message'    => $errors_message,
                    'errors'     => $errorsArray,
                    'rows_total' => 0,
                ], HTTP_RESPONSE_BAD_REQUEST );

            } //if ( isset($respArray->success) and empty($respArray->success)) {
            $loggedUser= $respArray->data->customer_details;

//            $this->respondWithToken($logged_user_token);

            return response()->json(['error_code' => 0, 'message' => '', "token" => $logged_user_token, 'user'=> $loggedUser ], HTTP_RESPONSE_OK );
            // if user details read was successful I return logged user

        }   // if( !empty($this->useAdmindashApi) and !empty($this->admindashApi)) {
```

But the problem is when I read data from my mysql db with app controls, I got

> Token Signature could not be verified

in console. I suppose that jwt-auth knows nothing about token I read from external API in $logged_user_token var.

Is there is a way to write value from $logged_user_token to jwt-auth token in my control above ?

```
"laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0",


"vue": "^2.5.17",
"axios": "^0.18",
"vuex": "^3.1.0"
```

Thanks!

**MODIFIED PART :**

In routes/api.php I have search-results described

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth',  'prefix' => 'personal', 'as' => 'personal.'], function ($router) {
    ...
    Route::post('search-results', 'SearchResultsController@remote_search_web');
    ...
});
```

and I got the error on first control method request like :

```
        axios.post(window.API_VERSION_LINK + '/personal/search-results', filters).then((response) => {
            this.is_page_loaded = true
            ...
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.showPopupMessage("Search", error.response.data.message, 'error');
            this.is_page_loaded = true
            this.showRunTimeError(error, this);
        });
```

**MODIFIED PART # 2 :**

Reading jwt docs I found here https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication :

> Of course you can also manually set the token as well, as needed if
>   there are other entry points into your application. e.g.
>   JWTAuth::setToken('foo.bar.baz');

So In my login control when I received token from external API I wrote :

```
$logged_user_token = $respArray->data->token;
...
$loggedUser= $respArray->data->customer_details;
\JWTAuth::setToken($logged_user_token);
return response()->json(['error_code' => 0, 'message' => '', "token" => $logged_user_token, 'user'=> $loggedUser ], HTTP_RESPONSE_OK );
```

But running this login method and referring to control's action when I read data from db I got the same error :

> JWT Token Signature could not be verified.

I found method in vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWT.php :

```
/**
 * Set the token.
 *
 * @param  \Tymon\JWTAuth\Token|string  $token
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setToken($token)
{
    $this->token = $token instanceof Token ? $token : new Token($token);

    return $this;
}
```

and see that $token parameter can be Token or string and then it must be converted to Token object.

But if I sent a string token from external API how have I render to it?

Does JWT has any apply/flash method to apply my new toaken to JWT ?

Comment: I know that does not answer to your question but you probably should use guzzle, itll make your CURL requests far easyer

Comment: I cant see any DB call, can i assume the issue is when you retrieve the user?

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED PART.  I practically have not work with guzzle, touched very few. Could you, please, provide a link to similar example?

Comment: Im not sure to understand. Is the process: axios->login->axios->search-results? And you issue is when you call search-result?

Comment: Guzzle is very easy to use, have look at the quickstart documentation, most case are covered

Comment: From now ill assume im right in my previous comment: the token came from another app, so it has been signed by the other app. You have to get the signature of the external app and register it in your app, because laravel try to verify the token. You could tell laravel explicitly to do not verify the signature but I can not remember how you do this, youll have to google it!

Comment: flow is:
1) User open login page
2) enter his credentials and run external api login request with user details
3) on success in the system O keep token and logged user info
4) user can open any app page, but some of them have search functionality
5) When user select search croteria and click search axios request '/personal/search-results' is run with mentioned error.

Comment: I googled with key "jwt-auth write token mannually" and did not find anything

Comment: Nice, so read my previous comment, the issue is probably what i mentionned: the token retrieved from the external app has not been signed by your app so when laravel verify the token, the signature is not valid

Comment: Do you have access to the external app jwt's signature mecanism?

Comment: I did not dev with laravel theses past years, but I can see at least 3 solution: 1) register the external app secret in your app. 2) override the jwt middleware and remove the part where it check the secret. 3) dont use the jwt middleware on this route and ask the external app to verify the token for you 4) dont use the jwt middleware and dont check the token. Not checking the token is a security issue

Comment: And for your google: 'laravel jwt manual secret" : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761451/how-to-correctly-set-a-jwt-secret-in-laravel-with-jwt-auth&ved=2ahUKEwi5pqj2_PXkAhUnzoUKHQpQBioQjjgwAXoECAgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2ySsn2tpAbRN4O5OBdk2_l

Comment: I do not speak about app secret, but about session token which is generated when user logged into system.
I do not like removing jwt middleware from the app...
\

Comment: The token is generated with a secret. This does looks like an auth token via the header not the session. Laravel surely check the auth header aswell by default. So it check the header and the session. In this case the header is set, so it check the header. Your problem is surely laravel checking the external app token if it is used via session or as a header

Comment: I did what you did sometime ago, on symfony. I ended up to check the jwt by myself via asking the external server because the external app used a secret based tactic instead of a RSA based tactic

Comment: Man try this: take the external secret, sey it in your configuration as your secret (if you can). If it works, the issue is this ( 99% chances)

Comment: When token is generated on login success this token is different any time I suppose

Comment: I search some simple method like  JWT::UseThis stringAsToken($string), if it exists

Comment: Please, look aT MODIFIED PART # 2

Comment: Man what you try can not work: you are setting the token into the middleware ( i suppose it work that way) then you write to the client. It is not persisted and it should not be persisted. Are you the developper of the app creating the token? The issue is that your token can not be verified. Laravel need to verify the token. To verify the token it will decode the first part, then calulate the signature. Then it will check the calculated signature with the last part of the token. If they are equal it assume the secret is correct. Its a bit different for RSA based token through but it is similar

Comment: To calculate the signature, it need the secret. In jwtAuth by default, the secret is automatically generated. The problem is that the secret generated from your app to calculate the signature is different than the one generating the token. So, the signature provided by your token is different than the one calculated by your jwtAuth. So your laravel can not verify the token. To give you a full answer i need more context. Can you get the correct secret? Is there a way to check the token on the third app via an API? If not, why do you verify the token? Do you need token's informations?